# PayPal Laravel 8 integration using srmklive error

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I want to integrate PayPal into my Laravel website but I'm getting this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Delta\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php on line 233

**Controller File**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout;

class PayPalController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->provider = new ExpressCheckout();
    }

    public function payment() {
        $data = [];
        $data['items'] = [
            [
                'name' => 'codechief.org',
                'price' => 100,
                'desc'  => 'Description goes herem',
                'qty' => 1
            ]
        ];

        $data['invoice_id'] = 1;
        $data['invoice_description'] = "Order #{$data['invoice_id']} Invoice";
        $data['return_url'] = route('payment.success');
        $data['cancel_url'] = route('payment.cancel');
        $data['total'] = 100;
        $provider = new ExpressCheckout;
        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data);
        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data, true);
        return redirect()->away($response['paypal_link']);
    }
```

Please give me a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your problem is that `$response['paypal_link']` isn't returning a link. Replace line:

```
return redirect()->away($response['paypal_link']);
```

With the code below:

```
if($response['paypal_link'] == null){
   // custom redirection
   return redirect()->back()->with(['error'=>'paypal link no set'])
}
return redirect()->away($response['paypal_link']);
```

For more info visit [laravel-paypal](https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal)

Comment: any documentation or tutorial link for Laravel paypal 3 which work with yout linked github?. I am only getting tutorial with Paypalexpress which is paypal 1.